# JavaCC - How can I make order not matter in this statement?

Tags: compiler-construction, javacc

I basically have the following statement, and want it to treat the stuff inside the same no matter what order it comes in. So for example, as the code currently is, it will accept "ABS(5) + 3" but not "3 + ABS(5)". Does anyone know how I can make it work in any order?

I thought putting everything as OR, and then surrounding that with the * would work, but that doesn't appear to have made much of a difference.

```
( ( s1=ABS() { s=s+s1; } )
| ( "+" { op="+"; s=s+op; }
  | "-" { op="-"; s=s+op; }
  | "*" { op="*"; s=s+op; }
  | "/" { op="/"; s=s+op; } ) 
| ( s1=EXPR() { s=s+s1; } ) )*
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are almost on the right track. You want that an ABS can be a kind of EXPR, then your rule for compound expressions can be

```
s = EXPR()
(
    (
      "+" { op="+"; s=s+op; } 
    | "-" { op="-"; s=s+op; } 
    | "*" { op="*"; s=s+op; }
    | "/" { op="/"; s=s+op; }
    )
    s1=EXPR() { s=s+s1; }
)*
```

The body of EXPR would look something like

```
( s = ABS() | s = NUMBER() )
{return s;}
```

As EJP points out in their answer, this doesn't deal with operator precedence, but then it's not clear that that is an immediate goal.  Also, what you've called Expr is usually called Primary.  See
[Parsing Expressions by Recursive Descent](http://www.engr.mun.ca/~theo/Misc/exp_parsing.htm) for more on precedence and associativity.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you're doing it completely wrong. The expression grammar should be much as for any other language, with `expression, term, factor,` and `primary.` Function calls like `ABS()` should appear in the production for `primary`, and nowhere else, along with literals, `'(' expression ')'` and so forth.